# No "Docked Mode" option in "Preview" settings in Android Studio once undocked

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, preview

Here is the Docked mode option for "Preview" window.

[image: Preview Setting with Docked mode option]

I removed the docked mode i.e. undocked it. And here is what I got.

[image: Preview Setting without Docked mode option]

There is no more "Docked Mode" option. Now I cannot properly work with designing layouts. Preview automatically hides when I change anything in the layout.

Answer (score 175, accepted):

Here is the simple solution for reverting to "Docked Mode".

1. Select the Preview Window
2. Go to Window menu > Active Tool Window

[image: Docked Mode in Window menu]

There you go. The Preview window is in Docked Mode. And there is the option for Docked Mode again.

[image: Preview Setting with Docked mode option]

Comment: My situation is worse: in "Active Tool Window" menu, the entry "Docked mode" is grayed out!

Comment: I unchecked "Floating mode" and "Docked mode" turned enabled. For future reference.

Comment: Time. Saved my time

Comment: Literally can't work without this being docked, thanks!

Comment: In Intellij you can dock and undock from the same place, which is obviously the correct design. The odd behavior remains in Studio 3.0.1 -- why is it not fixed?

Answer (score 9):

`Option 1`

First open any `layout` file to set the `preview` as `active window`. Then as the first answer says, goto `Window` in menu > `Active Tool Window` > Select `Pinned Mode`, `Docked Mode` and `Split Mode`

`Option 2`

Open a `layout` file. If the preview window doesn't appear, first make it visible by clicking `View` in menu > `Tool Windows` > `Preview`. Now preview window will appear. Then `right click` on the `Toolbar` in the `preview window` itself (the one with blue color)[image: image here] to show a list of options. Then there, select `Pinned Mode`, `Docked Mode` and `Split Mode`

Regards.

Answer (score 4):

The first answer is right, but you must *first* click Preview Window. Then you go to Window menu > Active Tool Window, choose Docked Window and Pinned Mode.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the simple solution for reverting to "Docked Mode" 
preview:

> Go to Window menu > Active Tool Window>Docked Mode(true).

Answer (score 2):

It didn't worked for me ,
But helped me ,Thank you.

Another Solution is
1.Select Preview window(Focus on it)
2.Unselect Floating mode and Pinned mode
3.goto  Window -> Active Tool Window ->
4.Unselect Floating mode and Pinned mode
5.Now you can see Docked window option here(Window -> Active Tool Window ->)
6.Select Docked Window

Answer (score 1):

If pin mode and docked mode options in window are in a gray color,
then First, go to window-> restore default layout-> again go to window->active tool window, pin mode and docked mode options will automatically made visible, so that we can select(or tick) them.