# How can I always show Android Studios Preview?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-13

I have probably hit some setting in Android Studio. So my problem is, my Preview window hides every time I click somewhere in the xml code.

Obviously I want the preview available the entire time I'm in the xml editor so that I can view my changes, and also without having to click the Preview button all the time.

Any ideas?

Comment: you mean the "design tab" ?

Comment: I mean the tab called "Preview"

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Found the answer. The tabs in Android Studio seem to have different amount of actions attached to them, but you can access some more if you go to Window -> Active Tool Window (with the preview tab selected/focused) and then click "Docked Mode", an option previously unavailable in the tabs options. When Docked mode is activated for the tab it is now available in the tab options!

Comment: it was driving me crazy. Thank's

Comment: Ironically, the option is there to uncheck it, but then it disappears and cannot be checked anymore except from that menu.

Comment: With better illustration : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30160082/1411055

Comment: I think `Pinned Mode` also needs to be selected along with the `Docked Mode`.

Answer (score 33):

I need preview layouts when writing code.

- click [android studio] > [preferences] > [layout editor]
- uncheck [Hide preview window when editing non-layout files.]

It works for me.

Comment: This was actually the setting I needed, it is very useful when editing dimensions.

Comment: Access _"[android studio] > [preferences]"_ in `File -> Settings... -> Editor -> Layout Editor`

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: You are a genius! Thank you so much!

Comment: This actually failed to work on my mac. I'm pretty sure it's a bug in the beta version of AS

Answer (score 3):

A shortcut is also available for seeing preview in android studio

press `ctrl` + `tab` and a switcher window will open

you can select preview from there using arrows key

Answer (score 2):

Click on View -> Tools Window - > Preview, on the left of preview have small setting icon, click on it and select Pinned Mode.

It works for me.

Comment: I tried the pinned mode earlier before I set it to docked, didn't work for me